# Do I have to state "am Wochenende" in my answer?

Tags: word-usage, word-order, time, modal-verb, question

So if I am asked the question:

> Was sollen Sie am Wochenende alles tun?

I respond with:

> Ich soll schwimmen gehen.

Where can I put Wochenende in my answer, or don't I need to?

Comment: "Was sollen Sie am Wochenende alles tun?" sounds very strange. Although it is grammatically right, no one would ask this in a normal situation. Do you have a context? Who ask who?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to, and it's more natural if you don't. But it would be fine (grammatically) to say

> Ich soll am Wochenende schwimmen gehen.

Note, however, that *sollen* sounds strange both in the question and in the answer. You probably mean *wollen*, since it's your own choice to go swimming, right? If you really want to express an obligation to go swimming, *müssen* is better than *sollen* (although I've heard the latter from people from northern Germany).

Comment: -1, I think this answer is too simple. in the right context "sollen" does not sound strange and "müssen" is not better. "am Wochenende" can be at the beginning or at the end of the sentence., too.

Comment: @miracle173: So when have you last asked someone out the blue *Was sollen Sie am Wochenende alles tun?*? Of course, one can think up some context for that, but it is much more likely that the OP meant *Was haben Sie am Wochenende alles vor?*.

Answer (score 0):

Others have pointed out that the phrasing of the question is unusual. It sounds like one’s superior checking if you correctly understood the tasks you must perform this week-end. And the answer almost sounds army-like to me (disclaimer: My hair is too long for the army).

That gotten aside, both phrases are *correct* and *idiomatic* (just unusual) so they can be used.

German has a very free word order as long as the finite verb occupies the second position in main clauses. So *all* of the following are possible — and there would be more possibilities if you had more moveable fragments:

> Am Wochenende soll ich schwimmen gehen.
>
> Ich soll am Wochenende schwimmen gehen.
>
> Schwimmen gehen soll ich am Wochenende.

The second option is ‘most natural’, the others all emphasise the part which is put in front.